# text align:center is not doing well with width and display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, width, inline, text-align

I am trying to have my text centered with a costum width.
Setting the width or max width will restore the position of the line to left. I am doing it like this:

[HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shQ44.png)

[CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vih3i.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QR4u.png)

I need to have custom width for each of them, have `<h6>` and `<a>` in one line and all of the content (including the border) in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the *parent* of the `h1` to `text-align:center`

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  background: lightgreen;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

Comment: It works great with the text align but when I set the width, it rolls back to thd left of the screen

Comment: Then you have **another** question and you should ask it separately with a demo of the issue. Obviously the width works in the demo above.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*without display: inline-block;*/
.h1{
  text-align: center !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

/*with display: inline-block;*/
.with_div{
  text-align: center;
}
.with_div h1{
  text-align: center !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!--  without display: inline-block; -->
<h1 class="h1">hello</h1>


<!-- with display: inline-block -->
<div class="with_div">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, regardless of whether it is in div or not with the CSS below. Similar to some of the others, but it also includes margin: auto; which will center the h1 even if it is displayed as inline or inline-block.

```
body{
  text-align: center;
}
h1{
  text-align: center !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: 1) If you add border to the h1 styling this should only add border to the 200px wide h1 element not the entire line (seems to work fine on my end). You can also set the top and bottom margins individually to make adjustments there.

2) Your original question only involved centering the text of the h1 element while being able to assign width and display either inline or inline-block. Without knowing the full scope of what you are trying to accomplish, it will be difficult to help you fully resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Without any wrapper div. CSS flex

```
h1{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: The text stil is not centered. Also, the width cannot be overrided